# Set iAd on top of the screen

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, iad

I have an iAd banner in my app. In the storyboard it is on top of everything (just above of the status bar). But, when it's loaded on the device it's displayed on the bottom of the screen. How can I change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're using `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true` in addition to implementing your own `ADBannerView`. The `ADBannerView` on the bottom of your screen is created by `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true`. `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true` can be used for a *no hassle* way of implementing iAd banners in your application. This will create an `ADBannerView` for you and show or hide the `ADBannerView` depending on whether it receives an ad or not from the iAd network.

Remove `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true` and implement your own `ADBannerView` if you'd like your `ADBannerView` to appear at the top of your `UIView`.